# How to handle multiple GA, AdWords, Remarketing tags

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I'm looking for some info on how to best manage multiple Google AdWords and other tags. My primary question is how to handle both the regular AdWord tag, the standard AdWords Remarketing tags and one of the custom AdWords Remarketing tags I created - say a 180 day RLSA list tag.  Do I need a separate tag call (vars, call to the conversion script and the noscript img tag)?  Is there a way to combine?

Also - being an ecommerce site - I see that for AdWords I need to add my sales total to the noscript img tag. But what about to the remarketing one? It has a default value of `1.00`, instructions make no mention to change that and the js version doesn't have any fields for it so I assume `1.00` is correct?

I am adding my entire code for the receipt of my store which has GA, standard AdWord and as well as the 180 day RLSA tag (which I assume is valid as the basic Remarketing tag).  Docs don't seem to ever address multiple tags unfortunately.

```
<!-- BEGIN: AdWords -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var google_conversion_id = 1002886276;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "DZAUCPS-jQoQhKmb3gM";
var google_conversion_value = 64.98;
var google_conversion_currency = "USD";
var google_remarketing_only = false;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
  <div style="display:inline;">
    <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1002886276/?value=64.98&amp;currency_code=USD&amp;label=DZAUCPS-jQoQhKmb3gM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0" />
  </div>
</noscript>
<!-- END: AdWords -->

<!-- BEGIN: Analytics -->
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
  i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
  i[r] = i[r] || function() {
    (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
  }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
  a = s.createElement(o),
    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
  a.async = 1;
  a.src = g;
  m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
ga('create', 'UA-40148609-3', {
  userId: '750fd151-6852-4a35-974d-c99f85f993f3'
});
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'title': 'Receipt'
});
ga('send', 'event', 'Completed Order', {
  category: 'Shopping',
  revenue: 64.98,
  id: 734352106,
  total: 64.98,
  shipping: 0,
  tax: 0,
  products: []
});
ga('set', 'ecomm_pagetype': 'purchase');
ga('set', 'ecomm_totalvalue', 64.98);
ga('set', 'ecomm_prodid': [218825388699, 118825388699])
</script>
<!-- END: Analytics -->

<!-- BEGIN: AdWords Remarketing -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var google_conversion_id = 1002886276;
var google_conversion_label = "9NX_CKTrkgoQhKmb3gM";
var google_custom_params = {
    ecomm_pagetype: 'purchase',
    ecomm_totalvalue: 64.98,
    ecomm_prodid: [218825388699, 118825388699]
  };
var google_remarketing_only = true;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
  <div style="display:inline;">
    <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/1002886276/?value=1.00&amp;currency_code=USD&amp;label=9NX_CKTrkgoQhKmb3gM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0" />
  </div>
</noscript>
<!-- END: AdWords Remarketing-->
```

Thanks for any assistance or official guides to multiple tag management.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, yet I came here from Google just before I found an answer to a similar problem, so I'll try to share my conclusions. It is best to integrate Google Tag Manager in case of having multiple codes. I consider it to be the best practice for your example.